# Removing space/&nbsp; with Tampermonkey?

Tags: html, css

This novel at [gravitytales](http://gravitytales.com/novel/the-city-of-terror/cot-chapter-44) has several **indentions/&nbsp/&emsp** within the span that makes reading annoying on my eyes. How can I use Tampermonkey(or other addons) to remove/hide these? Would it be possible to have it usable globally for most sites that adds indentions like that in every paragraph?

```
<span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; This scene lasted for twenty minutes.</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new Tampermonkey script will do the job. Something like that...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         removing_space_demo
// @namespace    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585747/removing-space-nbsp-with-tampermonkey
// @version      0.1
// @description  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585747/removing-space-nbsp-with-tampermonkey
// @author       You
// @match        http://gravitytales.com/novel/the-city-of-terror/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var cleanme = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(var i = 0; i < cleanme.length; i++){
        cleanme[i].innerHTML = cleanme[i].innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;{1,}/g,' ').replace(/  {2,}/g,' ');
    }
})();
```